# Stop/kill running script if $USER != "root"

Tags: bash, scripts, root, kill

I'm working on a scripts that needs to be executed as root, else it should stop everything.

```
#!/bin/bash
validationRoot() {
    if [ $USER != 'root' ]
        then
            echo "You're not root! You can't use this script."

    fi
}
validationRoot;
echo "You're root!"
```

I don't know what to add add after `echo "You're not root! You can't use this script."` to stop the execution.

Comment: I would add an "exit".

Comment: Note that if you `source` the script and run an `exit` - the shell instance will close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would have done this like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Mind that id=0 is what is used inside the kernel to identify the superuser (or root).

---

edit: it will be even better to redirect to STDERR.

---

Here is a one-liner :)

```
(( EUID )) && echo ‘You need to be root.’ && exit 1
```